# MATLAB error: converting expression containing remaining symbolic function calls into double array

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I am supposed to solve integrals using numerical and symbolical integration and compare the results afterwards.
Here is my code, where I define a function, then integrate it using methods from symbolic and numeric toolboxes accordingly:

```
syms x;
functions = cell(1, 3);
functions{1} = (1 + x - x^2) / sqrt((1 - x^2)^3);
ranges = [4, 10; -9, 0; 2, 10];
figure;
for i = 1:2
fprintf('Function %d: %s\n', i, char(functions{i}));
antiderivative = int(functions{i}, x);
fprintf('Antiderivative: %s\n', char(antiderivative));
a = ranges(i, 1);
b = ranges(i, 2);
num_result = zeros(1, (b - a) / 0.01);
sym_result = zeros(1, (b - a) / 0.01);
x_vals = a:0.01:b-0.01;
for j = 1:length(x_vals)
num_result(j) = integral(@(t) double(subs(functions{i}, x, t)), x_vals(j), x_vals(j) + 0.01);
sym_result(j) = double(subs(antiderivative, x, x_vals(j) + 0.01) - subs(antiderivative, x, x_vals(j)));
end
```

However, when trying to solve [this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAAWM.jpg), Matlab is throwing the error below:

```
Error using symengineUnable to convert expression containing remaining symbolic function calls into
double array. Argument must be expression that evaluates to number.Error in sym/double (line 761)
Xstr = mupadmex('symobj::double', S.s, 0);
```

The method works fine for other problems that don't have complex numbers. I already tried to search for this error online, the only solution provided is not using symbolic toolbox, which unfortunately I have to.